# returning the index in an insertion sorting

Tags: matlab, sorting

I want to know how to return the indices of the original elements in the insertion sort algorithm such as the function `[B,IX] = sort(A,...)` in matlab.

The algorithm is:

```
function list = insertionSort(list)

    for i = (2:numel(list))

        value = list(i);
        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 1) && (list(j) > value)
            list(j+1) = list(j);
            j = j-1;
        end

        list(j+1) = value;

    end %for
end %insertionSort
```

I want a function `[list indx]= insSort(list)` to return the sorted elements with its original indices.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why are you writing your own sort algorithm when MATLABs `sort` method will be faster pretty much 100% of the time?

Comment: sort method in matlab is depending on the quick sort which is slower than insertion sort in a nearly ordered data which is the case of my data.

Comment: You should read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/an-adventure-of-sortsbehind-the-scenes-of-a-matlab-upgrade.html) MATLAB blog post. As far as I can tell, MATLAB already drops down to an insert sort after a certain point, so I would be surprised if a pure insert-sort would be faster. Not to mention the fact that `sort` is native compiled code, which is going to be very hard to beat with just MATLAB code.

Comment: you are right, my claim was based on the info here [link] (http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) without coding,,, but after trying many samples the built-in sort in matlab is faster than the insertion even in the case of nearly sorted data..... Thank you for your valuable comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this isn't homework.

```
function [ind, list] = insertionSort(list)

    ind = [1:length(list)]'; % build list of indicies

    for i = (2:numel(list))

        value = list(i);
        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 1) && (list(j) > value)
            list(j+1) = list(j);
            ind(j+1) = ind(j); % copy index when you shift
            j = j-1;
        end

        list(j+1) = value;
        ind(j+1) = i; % write final index location

    end
end
```

Comment: It's not.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: also, i didnt check the speed of this with any large data sets, so make sure you profile it. sorting large data sets efficently is kind of a black art

Comment: it works well and of course the algorithm becomes very slow while sorting the last part of the data :)

Comment: yeah, unless you are tailoring your function to a very specific dataset, its hard to beat the efficency of profesionally coded sort algorithms.

Comment: that's right !last version of sort in matlab  implements 3 level sorting as in that link http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/an-adventure-of-sortsbehind-the-scenes-of-a-matlab-upgrade.html as MrAzzaman mentioned in a previous comment